# Create new Event using the iOS API

Tags: salesforce-id, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I am new to SalesForce and the iOS API, but not new to IOS. Does anyone know how I can create a new Event in SalesForce using the iOS API?

Comment: What have you tried so far? On SFSE it's best practice to show exactly where you're stuck. Creating objects from the iOS SDK is pretty straight forward as shown in the docs, check out the `requestForCreateWithObjectType:` method.

Comment: Thanks, I finally found those methods. I was just so new to it I was getting overwhelmed with all of the methods that I might need to use.

Answer (score 3):

I contributed some [nifty block methods](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/blob/master/native/SalesforceNativeSDK/SalesforceNativeSDK/Classes/SFRestAPI%2BBlocks.h) to the SDK that make this very easy. See this method:

```
- (SFRestRequest *) performCreateWithObjectType:(NSString *)objectType 
                                         fields:(NSDictionary *)fields 
                                      failBlock:(SFRestFailBlock)failBlock 
                                  completeBlock:(SFRestDictionaryResponseBlock)completeBlock;
```

And how you might use it:

```
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] performCreateWithObjectType:@"Event" 
                                                 fields:@{ @"SomeField" : @"Some Value" }
                                              failBlock:^(NSError *err) { NSLog(@"Failed with %@", err); }
                                          completeBlock:^(NSDictionary *dict) { NSLog(@"Success with %@", dict); }];
```

Comment: I worked on a new iOS project recently and was excited to see the block methods, way easier to deal with!